# Go : Fyne (Fyne.io) keyboard shortcuts do not work on the following example on Mac OS:

Tags: go, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts, fyne

The Fyne keyboard shortcuts do not work on the following snippet:

```
    // Ctrl + F to find
    ctrlF := desktop.CustomShortcut{KeyName: fyne.KeyF, Modifier:    desktop.ControlModifier}
    w.Canvas().AddShortcut(&ctrlF, func(shortcut fyne.Shortcut) {
        find(entry, w)
    })
```

This snippet is taken from:

```
https://github.com/Lucifer25x/fyne-text-editor
```

more specifically:

```
https://github.com/Lucifer25x/fyne-text-editor/blob/main/src/main.go
```

I used :

```
  Mac mini M1
  fyne.io/fyne/v2 v2.1.3
  go version go1.18 darwin/arm64
```

- The odd part is that the code compiles without warning.
- Any clue about what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Random question - does cmd+F work instead? There is some macOS specific magic and we may have crossed wires…

Comment: No, I tried. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Best to open an issue on GitHub. If code looks like it should work but doesn’t with Fyne then it probably is not an error at your end.